# What is the best way to stored pictures in a visual studio generated program?

Tags: c#, database, image, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

I wanted to create a program which contain database to supports sells.
The program will be develop using Visual Studio 2010 and connect with database using Ms.Access.
I would like to include a pictures of every product stored in the database.
I want to know the best way to store the picture in this case.

Comment: Quite broad but I think it's best to store it on disk and put a reference to the file in the database. This makes it easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) field for storing files(pictures, texts etc) directly into the `Database` follow the link for the insertion and selection process with the blob field [Uploading and Downloading BLOBs to Microsoft Access](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16851/Uploading-and-Downloading-BLOBs-to-Microsoft-Acces)